# Rule engine to filter multiple input objects based on multiple criteria

Tags: java, oop, object, design-patterns

I want to design a rule engine to filter incoming objects as follow:

At the beginning, I have three different classes: A, B, C. The list of classes is dynamic, i.e: I wanna extend this to work with class D, E, etc if D and E will be added later.

```
public class A {
   int a1;
   String a2;
   boolean a3;
   Date a4;
   List<String> a5;
   ...
}

public class B {
   String b1;
   boolean b2;
   Date b3;
   long b4;
   ...
}

public class C {
   String c1;
   boolean c2;
   Date c3;
   long c4;
   ...
}
```

There will be different objects of class A, B, or C that are gonna be filtered by my rule engine.

The users can define different rules based on a set of predefined operations that each member variable of a class can possibly have.

An example of some operations:

- a1 can have operations like: >=, <=, or between some range, etc.
- a2 can have operations like: is not, or is, etc.
- a3 can only be true or false.
- a4 can be: before certain date, after certain date, or between, etc.
- a5 can be: exists or not exists in the list, etc.

Some example rules for an object of class A would be:

- a1 is between 0 and 100, and a2 is not "ABC", and a3 is false, and a4 is before today, and a5 contains "cdf", etc.
- a2 is "abc", and a3 is true, and a4 is between some date range.
- etc.

One bullet is one rule. In a rule, there can be one criterion or more criteria (multiple criterion's that AND's together).

Each criterion is defined by a member variable with an operation that I can apply on that variable.

The rule engine must be able to process rules defined by users for each object of class A, B, or C. For every rule (A Rule, B Rule, or C Rule) coming in, the return will be a list of objects that matched the specified rule.

I can create Criterion, Criteria, ARule, BRule, CRule, Operation objects, etc; and I can go with the Brute Force way of doing things; but that's gonna be a lot of if...else... statements.

I appreciate all ideas of any design patterns/design method that I can use to make this clean and extendable.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Maybe you need to look at Drools: https://www.drools.org/.

Comment: The rules are in code, or do you need to store them somewhere? i.e. text file, database, etc

Comment: @tsolakp: I would like to develop this small engine by myself. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner for now, let have the rule in the code, but I would also wanna to save and load rule in the future, so that's something I need to take care of later on.

Comment: @GhostCat Hi there, I think you stepped over the line. There's no point to down vote my question. I just wanna get some ideas that I can start working on this. This is just asking for ideas. If I already wrote codes, I won't post it as A, B, or C classes. Where did I mention that I need code samples? Hope you understand.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a rule is actually a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) that is formed by *and*-ing other predicates. With Java 8, you can let the users define predicates for properties:

```
Predicate<A> operationA1 = a -> a.getA1() >= 10;           // a1 is int
Predicate<A> operationA2 = a -> a.getA2().startsWith("a"); // a2 is String
Predicate<A> operationA3 = a -> a.getA3(); // == true;        a3 is boolean

Predicate<A> ruleA = operationA1.and(operationA2).and(operationA3);
```

Now you can stream your `List<A>`, filter and collect to a new list:

```
List<A> result = listOfA.stream()
    .filter(ruleA)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use similar approaches for `B` and `C`.

Now, there are several ways to abstract all this. Here's one possible solution:

```
public static <T, P> Predicate<T> operation(
        Function<T, P> extractor, 
        Predicate<P> condition) {

    return t -> condition.test(extractor.apply(t));
}
```

This method creates a predicate (that represents one of your operations) based on a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) that will extract the property from either `A`, `B` or `C` (or future classes) and on a `Predicate` over that property.

For the same examples I've shown above, you could use it this way:

```
Predicate<A> operation1A = operation(A::getA1, p -> p >= 10);
Predicate<A> operation2A = operation(A::getA2, p -> p.startsWith("a"));
Predicate<A> operation3A = operation(A::getA3, p -> p); // p == true ?
```

But, as the method is generic, you can also use it for instances of `B`:

```
Predicate<B> operation1B = operation(B::getA1, p -> p.startsWith("z"));
Predicate<B> operation2B = operation(B::getA2, p -> !p); // p == false ?
Predicate<B> operation3B = operation(B::getA3, p -> p.before(new Date()));
```

Now that you have defined some operations, you need a generic way to create a rule out from the operations:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> rule(Predicate<T>... operations) {
    return Arrays.stream(operations).reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(t -> true);
}
```

This method creates a rule by *and*-ing the given operations. It first creates a stream from the given array and then reduces this stream by applying the [`Predicate#and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) method to the operations. You can check the [`Arrays#stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-), [`Stream#reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) and [`Optional#orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) docs for details.

So, to create a rule for `A`, you could do:

```
Predicate<A> ruleA = rule(
    operation(A::getA1, p -> p >= 10),
    operation(A::getA2, p -> p.startsWith("a")),
    operation(A::getA3, p -> p));

List<A> result = listOfA.stream()
    .filter(ruleA)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your promptly response. This is a good start for me. However, how do I associate the Rule object with your proposed design? I want to name the Rule, then have a list of criteria associated with each Rule so that I can save rules to database and load them later for reuse.

Comment: @Steven Hi! Well, you can either have `Criteria` and `Rule` classes that implement `Predicate`, or you might have an attribute of type `Predicate` within those classes. Of course, those classes can also have a `name` attribute. And the `Rule` class can have an attribute that is `List<Criteria> criterion`, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.